# How frequently does the while loop run in the Linux kernel cpu_idle()?

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler

By observing the Linux kernel 2.6.33, it seems that cpu_idle() is running its while loop which contains pm_idle() and schedule() around 10ms in my system. But I am wondering where the system is determined to get into pm_idle() at this certain rate. Is there somewhere else a longest task runnable duration after which the system will enter idle?

THanks,
Philip

Comment: Isn't this related to the CONFIG_HZ setting?

Comment: CONFIG_NO_HZ only disables time tick when CPU is in idle mode. But once CPU exits from idle, how soon will it get into idle again?